# tensorflow eager and imperative custom layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, eager

In one deep learning notes (Stanford cs20si), I once saw the following statement regarding eager. I don't quite understand what does the imperative custom layers indicate, and how to understand this code example in the context of imperative custom layers?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally, using `tensorflow` you are not able to access the content of a `tensor` directly. This means, that you are not able to use `if`-statements. Instead, you have to construct both possible branches of the branch and then use `tf.conditional` to include a node which switches between these two, depending on the content of a `tensor`. This makes it sometimes hard to implement imperative commands in layers.

The example you posted above show, that you are now (with `eager execution`) able to access the content of `tensors`, which means, that you can write all the `if`-statements, `for`-loops and so on, directly in `python` and you do not have to construct a huge graph on your own for each possibility. As the code inside the layer is now executed just like a normal imperative programming language, you can call this kind of layer an `imperative layer` - this is identical to the motivation behind `PyTorch`.